# Hit counter for pages in Django

Tags: django

I want to have a page counter that displays the number of visitors who have viewed a particular page on my site. Is it possible to do this using Django?

Comment: Thank You For Advice ..... Im sorry but my english is few

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a Django app for that problem called [django-hitcount](http://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount). It's easy to use, and reusable in any of your projects.

Comment: How can i implement it in the third party apps like mezzanine or zinnia

Answer (score 11):

A "page counter" is what?  A persistent piece of data which gets updated by view functions and displayed by a template.

As you are no doubt already aware, all Django things have the following parts.

1. Model
2. View Function
3. Template

**Model**

If you want to keep the page counter in the database, you need a Django model.

```
class PageCounter( Model ):
```

You need to put a row into this model.  Usually a "fixture" will help do this, since it's one row and you only put it in once when doing a syncdb.

**View Function**

Then you need to fetch and update the page counter in your view function.

```
pageCounter= PageCounter.objects.all()[0] 
pageCounter.count += 1
pageCounter.save()
```

**Template**

Now you need to provide the value to your templates so it can be displayed.

Comment: what about page refreshs ?

Comment: yeah @Lott what about page refreshes, can we do like -> create a field with manytomany relation with user in the post and increment the user counter in the detail view of the post ,then we can show the views by just counting the number of the users in the field, But that will not work for Anonymous User

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but occasionally people might have the same question.

If you want to avoid a third party library and prevent the counter being updated at every page refresh you could do the following Mixin (building on S.Lott's answer)

```
class BlogPostCounterMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogPostCounterMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        if not blog_post_slug in self.request.session:
            bp = BlogPost.objects.filter(slug=blog_post_slug).update(counter=+1)
            # Insert the slug into the session as the user has seen it
            self.request.session[blog_post_slug] = blog_post_slug
    return context
```

It checks if the accessed model has been stored in the session. If it has been stored in the session, it skips incrementing, else it increments the counter and adds the slug of the model to the session preventing increments for page refreshes.

Note: This is a Mixin which you require to add into your view.

Comment: Where should i put this?

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I appreciate if @IVI updates his answer to show how to use/call that mixin.